# Error when accessing allocated memory in c

Tags: c

If understand my own code correctly I am allocating space for 3 pointers pointing to a data type `ListNode` and then looping three times and adding a number to each node.
I know that the nodes are not connected to one another

now when I try to access any node from the allocated space I get the error commented in the bottom of the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
    } ListNode;

int main(void)
{    
    int nums[] = {2,3,4};

    ListNode * ptr = (ListNode*)malloc(3*sizeof(ListNode*));
    
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]); i++ )
    {
        ListNode new;
        new.val = nums[i];
        ptr[i] = new;
    }

    printf("%d \n",ptr[0].val);

    free(ptr);
    return 0; 
}
/*
Error: 
malloc(): corrupted top size
Aborted (core dumped)
*/
```

why do I get this error and how to properly access each node in the allocated space

Comment: You are allocating space just for pointers, not the structures. In consequence, you are writing beyond the end, which results in the error you get. -- I'm sure, SO has lots of duplicates, but I lack the time to look for a good one.

Comment: `sizeof(ListNode*) != sizeof(ListNode)`

Comment: Besides that, you don't create a list but an array.

Comment: Side note: `(ListNode*)malloc` -> `malloc`, the casts are useless with `malloc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allocating enough space:

```
ListNode * ptr = (ListNode*)malloc(3*sizeof(ListNode*));
```

Here you're attempting to dynamically allocate a 3 element of array of `ListNode` structs, but you're instead allocating space for 3 *pointers* to `ListNode`.  These pointers are smaller that the structs, so you end up writing past the end of allocated memory, triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and a crash.

You want to allocate space for 3 structs, not 3 pointers:

```
ListNode * ptr = (ListNode*)malloc(3*sizeof(ListNode));
```

Or better yet:

```
ListNode * ptr = (ListNode*)malloc(3 * sizeof *ptr);
```

As this doesn't depend on what the type of `ptr` is.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int nums[] = {2,3,4};
    size_t k = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]);

    ListNode * ptr = malloc(k*sizeof(ListNode));
```

1. Do not cast the malloc's result for reasons you can find in many places, including on SO.
2. Allocate `COUNT` *times* `sizeof(object)`, not `sizeof(object*)` bytes.